# selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element using Selenium ChromeDriver Chrome with Python

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver, webdriverwait

I am building a web scraper that scrapes citation data from the Web of Science. On Friday, I finalized that part of the program, but today it has stopped working and when I try to access the citation data via Selenium I get a NoSuchElementException. I have tried using different ways (id, class, xpath, css selector) of clicking on this one specific element, but it always throws the error. 
Here is my code, which was working and now is not:

```py
url = 'https://apps.webofknowledge.com/Search.do?product=UA&SID=8F2pCcE8ApJDSKZLHfF&search_mode=GeneralSearch&prID=acd62bc2-0ee0-47a1-a85d-12009db3c2f5'
driver.get(url)
citers_num = driver.find_element_by_class_name('snowplow-citation-network-times-cited-count-link')
citers_num.click()
```

Here is the html:

```html
<div class="search-results-data-cite">Times Cited: <a class="snowplow-    times-cited-link" title="View all of the articles that cite this one"     href="/CitingArticles.do     product=WOS&amp;SID=5FAYgZP1cYhuG9LGN3I&amp;search_mode=CitingArticles&amp;parentProduct=WOS&amp;parentQid=18&amp;parentDoc=12&amp;REFID=84460199&amp;excludeEventConfig=ExcludeIfFromNonInterProduct">313</a>
```

Here is the error I've been getting as of today:

```
citers_num = driver.find_element_by_class_name('snowplow-citation-network-all-times-cited')
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 564, in find_element_by_class_name
    return self.find_element(by=By.CLASS_NAME, value=name)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 978, in find_element
    'value': value})['value']
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"class name","selector":"snowplow-citation-network-all-times-cited"}
  (Session info: chrome=75.0.3770.80)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=74.0.3729.6 (255758eccf3d244491b8a1317aa76e1ce10d57e9-refs/branch-heads/3729@{#29}),platform=Mac OS X 10.14.1 x86_64)
```

I know that there are other similar questions on here, but none of them have been able to help me. Thank you!

Comment: I suggest using the ```find_element_by_xpath()``` function for more precision(but less readability). find the xpath by right clicking the source in the "inspect element" section of your browser.

Comment: I have tried that and the same thing happens.

Comment: According to your own post, the class name is `snowplow-    times-cited-link`, not `snowplow-citation-network-all-times-cited`....

Answer (score 0):

Use `Webdriverwait` and following `xpath` to click on that.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//div[@class='search-results-data-cite'][contains(.,'Times Cited:')]/a"))).click()
```

OR css following css selector.

```
WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"div.search-results-data-cite a"))).click()
```

make sure you have imported above imports before use the code.

Comment: Thank you, but then I get a TimeoutException even when decreasing the wait time.

Comment: have you provided right html content.based on your html tag you have posted it should work.

Comment: I have. It was working on Friday and now it's stopped working even though I haven't edited it at all.

Answer (score 0):

There are exactly two issues out there. As you are attempting a `click()` you need to to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.search-results-data-cite a[class*='times-cited-link'][href^='/CitingArticles']"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='search-results-data-cite']//a[@title='View all of the articles that cite this one' and starts-with(@href, '/CitingArticles')]"))).click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

The next issue is the **incompatibility** between the version of the binaries you are using as follows:

- You are using *chromedriver=74.0*
- Release Notes of [*chromedriver=74.0*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/74.0.3729.6/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following :

> Supports **Chrome v74**

- You are using *chrome=75.0* which have got updated by the recent push.
- Release Notes of [*ChromeDriver v75.0*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/75.0.3770.8/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following :

> Supports **Chrome v75**

So there is a clear mismatch between *ChromeDriver v74.0* and the *Chrome Browser v75.0* and to address it you need to either:

- Keep *Chrome v75* and upgrade *ChromeDriver* to **ChromeDriver v75** level.
- Keep *ChromeDriver v74* and downgrade *Chrome* to **Chrome v74** level.

Comment: Thank you, but my chrome and chrome driver were already compatible and neither of those approaches work. I think I may have gotten myself banned from Web of Science and that might be the root of the problem, because this was working fine a few days ago and the HTML for the site hasn't changed.